# conflict between cython and ctypes using sizeof function

Tags: cython, ctypes

I defined a class SomeClass(ctypes.Structure) in some.py file and imported it in some.pyx file like this:

```
from ctypes import memset, addressof, sizeof
from some import SomeClass
someInstance = SomeClass()
memset(addressof(someInstance), 0, sizeof(SomeClass))
```

But the sizeof function always return 8, no matter how many fields in SomeClass.
I think the sizeof function is the built-in function in cython, not the ctypes's. If I import it like this, the size of SomeClass is correct:

```
from ctypes import memset, addressof, sizeof as csizeof
memset(addressof(someInstance), 0, csizeof(SomeClass))
```

Comment: It looks like you've already solved the problem, so what is the question?

Comment: My question is: why I declared 'from ctypes import sizeof' is not useful? It shouldn't use the default sizeof in cython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is consistent with the behavior for calling `cdef` functions and is the only sensible thing for Cython to do.

When interacting with C (e.g. calling external modules and calling `cdef` functions) Cython decides which function to call at compile time:

```
cdef a():
   print("Hi")

from some_module import a
a() # will print Hi - this is decided by the functions Cython knows about when it compiles
```

`import` statements are evaluated at runtime. There is no way Cython can know about them at compile time because the variables they define can be reassigned at will.

```
from some_module import a_function
del globals()['a_{}'.format('func')+'tion']
a_function() # no longer defined here, but how can Cython know?
```

If Cython were to attempt to work out if a `cdef` function had been overridden by something in `globals` (i.e. something that's been imported) then you'd lose most of the speed gains from Cython - otherwise fast C-only code would require a fairly expensive dictionary lookup:

```
 cdef char* a = <char>malloc(sizeof(char))
```

Would be translated to something nonsensical like

```
 # pseudocode!
 try:
     char_tmp = globals()['char']
 except KeyError:
     char_tmp = built_in_char
 try:
     sizeof_tmp = globals()['sizeof']
 except KeyError:
     sizeof_tmp = built_in_sizeof

 try:
     malloc_tmp = globals()['malloc']
 except KeyError:
     malloc_tmp = built_in_malloc
 a = <char>malloc_tmp(sizeof_tmp(char_tmp))
```

Additionally this simple statement could not be used in multithreaded code, since it now depends on the Python interpreter which can only run one thread at once.

Therefore the only solution which doesn't completely break Cython is to chose to use the C `sizeof` at compile time, and lose the ability to override it by importing it.

---

Extra note: in practice the C `sizeof` is evaluated as a constant at compile time rather than called at run time, so your usage makes even less sense.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very clear. Additionally, the `SomeClass` is a sub-class of `ctypes.Structure`. I can only get its size using `ctypes.sizeof`, not the C `sizeof`. Or, how can I use the fast C `sizeof` to do it? Moreover, I wonder is the `ctypes.sizeof` very slow, not implemented using C code?

Comment: As you say, you should use `ctypes.sizeof` for `someClass`. This is something you should only need to do once (the `sizeof(someClass)` will always be the same on the same computer) so it isn't worth worrying about speed.